# Compiling/Building C# Project Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a project in c# that I would like to compile programmatically and put it in Release folder.

I am using CodeDomProvider, here below is my code:

```
 class Compiler
    {
      public static void Build(string filename,string outputAssemblyPath)
        {

            CodeDomProvider cdp = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
            CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters()
            {
                GenerateExecutable = true,
                GenerateInMemory = true,
                IncludeDebugInformation = true,
                OutputAssembly = outputAssemblyPath
            };
            CompilerResults result = cdp.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, filename);

            foreach (string s in result.Output)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
}
```

I am calling Build method the following way:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Compiler.Build("C:/Projects/Project1/alan.project/Project1.csproj", "C:/Projects/Project1/alan.project/bin/Release/");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

All I want to do is instead of clicking "Rebuild" and have my project compiled in the Release directory, I want it done programmatically.

Comment: Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/generating-and-compiling-source-code-from-a-codedom-graph? There seems to be an `OutputAssembly`-property on the `CompilerParameter`-argument provided to the `CompileFrom...`-method.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I tried the example in that webpage but it doesn't work, I am including the path of "Program.cs" as a first parameter and the location of the exe file as the second param. But there is error CS1504 'path/of/my/compiler/project/bin/release/Program.cs' could not be opened. Why is it reference to my compiler project and not to the project I want to compile?

Comment: It is principle to build with CodeDomProvider?

Comment: Did you tried `CompilerOptions` with `/out` argument? 
`/out:D:\\Alan\\AssemblyName`

Comment: @UserName Not necessarily with CodeDomProvider, any other one is good, I will try your suggestion

Comment: MSBuild have nice SDK that allow perform build programmatically.

Comment: @UserName Thank you I think this is the solution I want, please could you answer how to use it so that I can give you the answer

Comment: You are setting **GenerateInMemory** property to true. No physical file will be created . Try to set it to false .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of decision it's using `MSBuild SDK`, that allows create custom task on `C#`. Through it you can controll build process, describe own logic.

---

```
using Microsoft.Build.Construction;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
using System.Linq;

namespace MSBuild.Common
{
    class Build : Task
    {
        [Required]
        public string Solution
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override bool Execute()
        {
            return BuildEngine2.BuildProjectFilesInParallel(SolutionFile.Parse(Solution).ProjectsByGuid.Select(p => p.Value.AbsolutePath).ToArray(), null, null, null, null, true, false);
        }
    }
}
```

This is task example. It's accept path to the solution and perform parallel compile its projects. You can add properties to [BuildProjectFilesInParallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.framework.ibuildengine2?view=netframework-4.7.1) that will describe build process.

---

Call of created task will be from the custom target:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" InitialTargets="EntryBuild">

    <UsingTask AssemblyFile="Build.dll" TaskName="Build" />

    <Target Name="EntryBuild">
        <Build Solution="$(Solution)" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

---

Execute it through `MSBuild CLI`:

```
msbuild.exe /t:Build.targets /p:Solutin=%pathToSolution%
```

[MSBuild Targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order#initial-targets) | [Task Writing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/task-writing)